# kendo-ui mobile listview headerTemplate date format

Tags: listview, mobile, kendo-ui

All,

I have the following code

```
$("#ulPremiseList").kendoMobileListView({ 
dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: data.Result, schema: "Result", group: 
"CreatedAt"}),
template: $("#customPremiseListViewTemplate").html(),
headerTemplate: "<h2>Date ${value} </h2>"          
});
```

I am trying to format the ${value} in the headerTemplate as a MM/dd/yyyy date

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [kendo.toString utility](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/kendo#methods-toString)